# Quick Select Parent and Child Objects in Outliner?

Tags: outliner

Is there a simple method for click-selecting an Object in the Outliner and also selecting its child Objects, in one go?  (Like holding Shift and clicking, for instance, though I know that one doesn't work.)

Eg:

I have a bunch of objects with child objects in them.  I want to drag them into a new Collection.  If I drag just the parent and move it then all of the child objects stay in the original collection.  (I find this to be an infuriating flaw in Blender's UI, but I digress.)

I know I can select the parent and then hold shift and click the last child object to select the hierarchy.  I also know that I can right-click and choose "Select Hierarchy."  Both options become tedious when you do them enough.

If there is a better way I would love to hear it!

Answer (score 3):

In the 3D viewport, this is easy.  It's shift ], shift [.  Unless it depends on initial startup interface choices, which isn't easy to check.  It's "select hierarchy" operation, with "child" and "parent" respectively, on extend.  (Shift on a selection is usually extend.)

That's not outliner, and there are outside cases where that won't work for you (parents or children in hidden collections), but it should be good enough most of the time.  Selections are echoed between outliner and 3D viewport, so selecting in 3D viewport will also select in the outliner, ready to be dragged to some hostile new collection.  (Poor objects.)

If you don't want to move your mouse off the outliner to call from a 3D viewport, you can still invoke a "select hierarchy" operation from a search there, but you'll have to adjust the operator settings manually, and it still won't select objects in hidden collections.

Comment: Thanks for your input Nathan. I'm aware of all of these functions, sadly none of which are the simple solution I'm after. Cheers.